# How to generate a real-time stream of data?

Tags: manipulate, streams, time-series, real-time

I'm experimenting with Inversion-of-Control (callback) programming patterns, and I would like a way to generate streams of data at specified real-time intervals.  I came up with the illustrated way to use Animate (or Manipulate) to do it, and that's fine for experiments with the notebook front end, but I would like to have pure-code solutions I could put in a .m package.  As always, I will be grateful for any hints, advice, and solutions!

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `RunScheduledTask` and related functions?

Comment: Not till now :)  Post this as answer and I'll mark it such!

Comment: I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`RunScheduledTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RunScheduledTask.html) or its relatives for this. For example, to append a random integer to `catch` once every two seconds you could do something like

```
catch = {};
task = RunScheduledTask[AppendTo[catch, RandomInteger[10]], 2];
```

You could also use [`CreateScheduledTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CreateScheduledTask.html) which is similar to `RunScheduledTask` except that the task won't be started automatically after it's been created. You'll have to use [`StartScheduledTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StartScheduledTask.html) to start it manually.

To start and stop the scheduled task you can use `StartScheduledTask[task]` and `StopScheduledTask[task]`, respectively, and `RemoveScheduledTask[task]` will remove the scheduled task once you're done with it.

Additional information about these functions is available in the [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/TimedEvaluations.html).